# How many Tortoise SVN directories do I need?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We currently have all our website files located in Tortoise SVN. Right now I have a local directory on my computer. These are "working files" on which I make updates. Then I copy and paste the updated file into SVN folders located on a remote server. This remote server actually has 3 folders for website files: Preview, Staging and Production. I paste the updated file into the Preview folder and check the result on the "Preview" site. Then I copy and paste the file into the Staging folder and check the result on the "staging" site. Finally I copy and paste the file into the Production folder and view it on the live site.

My question is...is all this necessary? Do I need to have the local directory, plus a Preview, Staging and Production folder? Can the process be streamlined?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are misunderstanding svn - you are not supposed to copy and paste between the directories but (and here I am just assuming the setup you have) use a svn repository to synchronise the content between the three instances (using checkout and commit).

The purpose of having multiple environments is to ensure the quality of the final production version. To check what the production will look like in a live environment before putting it in a live environment. 
However, having a preview AND a staging environment in addition to production seems like an overkill to me if this is a simple website - I think you can easily drop one of them.

Some of this work could be automated using a continuous integration tool such as Jenkins or TeamCity (the latter is said to be easier to use)

If you provide more details about your environment and the project you are working on, maybe I can help you further.